# C#. Получение данных из консольного приложения

Tags: c#, консоль

Имеется консольное приложение, которое после запуска выводит на экран некоторую информацию. Мне требуется из моего приложения запустить это приложение и по окончанию его работы получить информацию, которая выводилась в консоль.
Приложение я запускаю так

```
string prog = "a.exe";
if (File.Exists(prog))
{
    Process.Start(prog);
}
```

Как мне получить информацию, которую выводит это приложение?

Answer (score 3):

Вот просетнький пример:

```
 var process = new Process();
 process.StartInfo.FileName = "a.exe";
 // Говорим что нужно редиректить выходной поток  
 process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
 // В StringBuilder будем добавлять полученные данные
 var sb = new StringBuilder();
 // Запускаем процесс
 process.Start();
 while (!proc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream) 
 {
    sb.Append(proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine());
 }
```

По окончании в `sb` будут весь выхлоп процесса. Есть так же возможность асинхронного чтения. Для этого Вам надо подписаться на событие [OutputDataReceived](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived(v=vs.110).aspx) и после метода `Start` процесса, вызвать у него [BeginOutputReadLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.diagnostics.process.beginoutputreadline(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Не знал про данное свойство
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

Comment: Пожалуйста! [MSDN][1] в помощь:)


  [1]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx